Is there an Solana Multisig Wallet (not solana cli), to sign an transaction as nonce authority
I need to withdraw MNDE from marinade.finance, but the owner wallet has anothet nonce authority.
I have the keypairs of both wallets (owner and nonce authority of the owner).
Is there and wallet to import the both keypairs in order to withdraw the MNDE?
